# como sobre poner un div con css y que solo se pueda ver parte de este div

Tags: css, css3, div, css-transform

hola que tal tengo una duda con respecto a css y como puedo lograr el diseño que me piden mostrar la parte de verde y amarillo
el div que esta inclinado lo hago con transform: matrix();
pero lo que no se es como ocultar la parte roja

[image: aca se ven dos 2 div uno sobre otro]

el resultado debe ser asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ademas de eso se pondra un texto en la parte amarilla

### ayuda no se como hacer eso

este seria el codigo

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ejemplo</title>
    <style>
        .contenedor{
            margin-top:100px;
            height:100px;
            text-align:center;
            border-color:green;
            border-style:solid;              
        }
        .contenido{
            transform: matrix(0.98, 0.17, 0.2, -0.98, 0, 0);
            -ms-transform: matrix(0.98, 0.17, 0.2, -0.98, 0, 0);
            -webkit-transform: matrix(0.98, 0.17, 0.2, -0.98, 0, 0);
            border-radius: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 191.39px;
            height: 149.09px;
            left:87%;
            top:1%;
            border-color:red;
            border-style:solid;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="contenido">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

me sale este resultado pero no lo necesitan si sino que salga el div verde incluyendo la parte del div rojo que esta dentro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por favor incluye ejemplo de tu código html y css. Suponiendo que tienes tu caja verde como `.contenedor` y dentro tienes tu otra caja roja `.contenido`. Podrías hacer algo como esto.

```
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="contenido">
  </div>
</div>

.contenedor {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: También se debe cambiar el valor `position` del contenido, y reubicarlo